# Difference between provides & output in pathom 3

Tags: clojure, resolver

What is the difference between provides & output here?

```
#com.wsscode.pathom3.connect.operation.Resolver
{:config
 #:com.wsscode.pathom3.connect.operation
 {:input [:ip]
  :provides {:longitude {}
             :latitude {}}
  :output [:longitude
           :latitude]
  :op-name com.wsscode.pathom3.demos.ip-weather/ip->lat-long},

 :resolve
 #object[com.wsscode.pathom3.demos.ip_weather$ip__GT_lat_long__17350
         0x4b7b5266
         "com.wsscode.pathom3.demos.ip_weather$ip__GT_lat_long__17350@4b7b5266"]}
```

From : https://pathom3.wsscode.com/docs/tutorial/#resolvers

Comment: For a proper answer I suspect we would need input from Wilker Lúcio, the author of pathom or somebody who knows pathom better than I do. Looking through the source and from the little playing around with pathom I've done: the `input` and `output` keys to a resolver are what you would typically use. It seems to me that the `provides` key is something pathom uses internally to describe the shape of the output data. I would guess it's used somehow in the resolver planning etc in the pathom internals, but again, I don't know pathom well enough to give an authoritative answer.

Comment: I would recommend joining the clojurians slack workspace and post your question on the pathom channel there. It tends to be quite responsive.

Comment: Sure. I'll join the slack channel & check there too. I found both the answer & suggestion very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

both the output and provides have the same data, but in different formats. The output uses the EQL format, which is more user-friendly and extensible. But for quick presence check, the vector format would require a scan to find an element, so the provides uses a map, which has constant access for verification, speeding up things for the processing code.